# What platforms are my projects compatible with?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I've known for some time that the different visual studio releases provide support for different operating systems. I've made a project in 2008, and need it to be compatible in XP, Vista, and Windows 7. I'm realizing now this may have been a mistake, and I maybe should have developed in 2003 or even 2005.

Question #1: Is there a way to get my project to run in XP and Vista? It runs in Windows 7, but I've tried it in Vista and it crashes before the welcome screen, and since XP is older than Vista, I'm guessing it has similar disastrous effects on XP as well.

Question #2: What is it that causes the differences between the releases, and why does my program only work in Windows 7 (that I know of) at the moment?

Thank you very much, I've tried to do research on the subject, but it's quite scattered out, and I figured quite a few of you have a lot of knowledge regarding my question.

Comment: Using C# and .NET, just so everyone knows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to try for #1:

- If you're on a 64 bit platform, [change your build target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180809%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to x86 - that should run on both architectures
- You can also [specify the .NET framework version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) - 2.0 is most ubiquitous and therefore most backward compatible. Just know what you're losing some 3.0 and 3.5 goodies
- Is your project using Windows 7-specific features? If so, then lose them.
- Any other dependencies on libraries that might not automatically exist on machines you deploy to?

You didn't specify but I'm guessing based on your previous questions that you're using C# and .NET.

For #2: It's probably symptoms of my troubleshooting suggestions for #1. Creating a 64 assembly and trying to run on 32 bit can fail. Running with a newer framework on a machine with an older .NET install might fail...

The strange thing about this is that usually there are very verbose .NET errors for this kind of stuff. Your symptoms actually sound more like c/C++ apps blowing up quietly... odd.

And to answer your title question: VS 2008, since it can target .NET 2.0, should be able to run on WinXP and 2003 Server w/o too much trouble. I think even Windows 2000 with the latest service pack can run .NET 2.0 apps.

Comment: +1 for looking at his post history. You're probably right at guessing C# which makes my answer less helpful. I will do that in the future to improve my answers.

Comment: I was actually just making sure. CODe and I worked on a question a few days ago. Thanks though.

Comment: Hey Paul! Thanks a million for your help, this is the same application by the way. ;)  So yes, it is a .NET app in C#. In regards to your answer, change it to 64 bit assembly, but how do I set it to an older .NET version?

Comment: No prob. That's why we're here. So, are you developing on a 64 bit box and defaulting to .NET 3.5?

Comment: @Paul: I am on a 64 bit machine with Windows 7 Pro. Unsure as to my .NET version... Changed build target to x86, still had the same effect in Windows Vista unfortunately. How do I go about changing the .NET version the program utilizes? Because I'm guessing the (older) .NET versions directly correlate to the other (older) operating systems...

Comment: There's your problem. By default any project you build on such a system will default to 64 bit platform and .NET version 3.5. Take a look at those links i put in my answer and change the target and .NET version. The resulting build should work just fine on a 32 bit WinXP.

Comment: Here's another link on the .NET framework version. (Office plugin specific but still fits.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Or: Right click on your project and select Properties. In the Application tab change your Target Framework to 2.0. Save, close properties and rebuild... Good luck. I need to sign off. Past midnight here in the central US.

Comment: @Paul: Unfortunately, it looks like changing to .NET 2.0 and the x86 assembly didn't change the result of attempting to run on Vista. Still crashes. :(  Any other ideas by chance...? FYI, I'm in the central US as well, just get most of my work done around this time. ;)

Comment: Do you have any error messages or anything? Without any error info the only thing i can think of is that you're using a Windows 7-specific feature that does not exist on earlier platforms. OR: you mentioned in previous posts that it's a sqlite project. Are there sqlite DLLs in place on that other machine?

Comment: If you don't have an install package and depend on libraries outside of the standard .NET offerings then you definitely need to get them to the other machine(s). I'm also concerned about a lack of error info. Are you using an empty try/catch block somewhere that's keeping error info from being presented to you?

Comment: @Myself: -1 for being a moron. Some of my dependent DLL's weren't being copied over, thus, the program was crashing. I do still have a few questions though Paul. Is there a way I can bundle my installation of this program with a .NET 3.5 install? Also, does Windows XP and Windows Vista both support 3.5?

Comment: You can bundle it all together by creating a simple installer. That would be another post... there are a dozen ways to do it, the simplest of which might be to use Visual Studio. Add a new deployment project etc. And yes, if .NET 3.4 is installed on XP and/or Vista it will work. For XP you need SP 2 or 3 but that's it.

Comment: Check out this tutorial for 2008 deployment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are writing C++

Your project is compatible with Visual Studio 2008. If install VS2008 on your vista test machine and compile it locally it should run there.

My deepest regrets. You are using "Windows Extensions". They are great, until you want to change something.

My best advice would be to do development on XP, since Windows is backwards compatible to 95.

One thing you could try is using the (Warning Level 4) \W4 compiler flag and fix all issues reported. . However, if you are where I think you are, this will be a very long list.

If there is a ANSI compilation flag I suggest it as well, but I don't believe Visual Studios has one (thus your problem)